# How to reference js/css files from other (blazor) library than itself?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, blazor

How can i reference/use css/cs files located in a referenced blazor project, different from current project in _host.cshtml?

I mean here:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
...
    <link href="_content/Aguacongas.AwsComponents/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <app>
    </app>
    <script src="_content/Aguacongas.AwsServices/main.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You seem to have supplied code that does what you are asking about...maybe clarify what you want to do differently?

Comment: The way you put an example of external js and css files, seems correct. What is the issue?

Comment: It was a random code sample from somewhere which I didn't notice it already contained the solution. thx for pointing that out.

Answer (score 3):

The solution is rather simple as in the random example already used: (didn't see that...)

```
<script src="_content/ExternalLibrary/main.bundle.js"></script>
```