# How i can add shared css between two Blazor Project?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, blazor, miui

I have two projects, one with MAUI, and another Blazor, do i have any chance to share one common css file between these two projects?

I already tried to add this to the shared project, but the problem, it's, I cannot get any access to it, from the launched project, because I don`t have it in www root.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reference js/css files from other (blazor) library than itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60533748/how-to-reference-js-css-files-from-other-blazor-library-than-itself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link to the CSS file must be - `<link src="_content/{ExternalLibrary}/{name}.css"></link>`   - Where `{ExternalLibrary}` it is the name of the Shared library, and `{name}` it`s the name of CSS file, which styles we want to import.
Also, this library must be a Razor class library.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a bundle to reuse static files such as js, css etc.

Check this article
https://www.syncfusion.com/faq/blazor/general/how-do-you-bundle-and-minify-the-css-and-js-files-in-blazor-applications